# How to set data to object in JS/TS?

Tags: javascript, typescript

At response to my api I must return a parsed data, which i set in belowed way to my `UserModelResponse` which i return in API:

```
        const userModelResponse = new UserModelResponse();

        userModelResponse.description = responseData.description;
        userModelResponse.full_name = responseData.full_name;
        userModelResponse.sex = responseData.sex ;


        const orders = [];
        responseOrderData.forEach((e) => {
            const orderModel = new OrderModel();

            orderModel.price = e.price;
            orderModel.weight = e.weight;
            orderModel.time = e.time;

            orders.push(orderModel );
        })
        userModelResponse.orders = orders ;
```

is there a better and faster way to set data from db(`responseData` and `responseOrderData`) to my `UserModelResponse`? thanks for any help

Comment: Assuming those are the only properties in your response data, just use `Object.assign`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a little more cleanly with Array.map, but the speed of it will be negligable:

```
userModelResponse.orders = responseOrderData.map((e) => {
  const orderModel = new OrderModel();
  orderModel.price = e.price;
  orderModel.weight = e.weight;
  orderModel.time = e.time;
  return orderModel;
});
```

If the `OrderModel` constructor accepts something like an object of default values, then you could do something like:

```
userModelResponse.orders = responseOrderData.map(e => new OrderModel(e));
```

Edit: Updated the `new OrderModel` part following @Bergi's comment.

The constructor of `OrderModel` would need to look something like:

```
class OrderModel {
  constructor(order) {
    this.price = order.price;
    this.weight = order.weight;
    this.time = order.time;
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: in second example, how constructor must look like in `OrderModel`?

Comment: Much simper: `new OrderModel(e)`

Comment: @svelteDev It must accept a single parameter and copy its properties onto itself.